# Create Youtube embed block with createBlock

Tags: javascript, block-editor

I was trying to use this to create a Youtube video block using JavaScript:

```js
// Define the YouTube video URL (replace with your desired URL)
const youtubeVideoURL = 'https://youtu.be/NNrj0N-yTnM';

// Create a new YouTube video block
const youtubeVideoBlock = wp.blocks.createBlock('core-embed', {
  url: youtubeVideoURL,
});
```

But I get the following error:

> Uncaught Error: Block type 'core-embed' is not registered.

That this means it's actually impossible to programmatically create an "embed" block for Youtube videos?

It works fine for paragraphs, quotes, images... so I'm surprised this is not working for embeds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps the name you're using is incorrect?

At least in [/block-library/src/embed/core-embeds.js](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/b35774d56866a6d54db04a396f13494c06c3069d/packages/block-library/src/embed/core-embeds.js) the different embed types seem to follow `core-embed/{source}` pattern on their names - e.g. `core-embed/youtube`. And the embed block itself has `core/embed` as its name.

Comment: `core-embed/youtube` won't work either. I get the following error in the JS console: *"blocks.min.js?ver=b5d3b99262dfb659bd26:3 Uncaught Error: Block type 'core-embed/youtube' is not registered."*

Comment: `core/embed` worked. Thanks!